# Auto-generating WSDL file for a Python Twisted SOAP Server

Tags: python, soap, wsdl, twisted

Any recommendations for auto-generating the WSDL for a Python/Twisted SOAP Server?

I've found lots of examples for taking an existing WSDL and generating the stubbed Python code, but am looking for the reverse operation.

Comment: Depending on what the stubbed code looks like, you should be able to introspect the Python code in some way, but it's difficult to say without seeing an example of the code you are trying to analyze.

Answer (score 0):

The point is, all the python libraries out there are not complete and no more supported as well.

There is a library we are working on and maintaining, called `soapbox`, on this [link](http://code.google.com/p/soapbox/).

This library has all the features that you need and more, and we are working on to add more features and capabilities.

Kindly note that, we are the only python soap library that is actively supported in the market, and because of this specific reason, people migrate from python to other languages when it comes to complex soap projects.

Let me know if you have further questions or enquiries.

Thanks!

Comment: is soapbox an active project? Can i consider using it in Production with Django/mod_wsgi/Apache?

Comment: Securecurve - I am having issues with soapbox. The WSDL I am working with is not getting properly interpreted into classes. Is there a way you could collaborat with me 1 to 1. I'd really appreciate your help on this.

Comment: @Guddu, Sure .. I'm just busy for the next week, I think I'll have some time to help you after .. I hope i'm not too late